# <canvas>... centrado dentro de un <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, responsive

Quizás sea una tontería para muchos o no se pero aun no soy muy bueno en CSS en temas de responsive desing y todo eso.

Bueno tengo un canvas que por decirlo así me renderiza un PDF, por esa parte todo bien pero el elemento canvas esta dentro de un div y por mas que quiera centrarlo no lo consigo siempre se mantiene pegado al la esquina derecha del div.

> HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/turn.min.js"></script>

<body>
            <div id="magazine">          
                    <canvas  id="the-canvas"></canvas>             
            </div>
   <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

> CSS

---

He intentado moverlo con (top, right...) o usando ***margin*** pero al intentar moverlo hacia el centro del div no pasa nada.

```
 #magazine{
        width: 1052px;
        height: 652px;  
        background-color: brown;
        margin: 5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

#the-canvas{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width:110%;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

> JS por si es necesario

```
       $(window).ready(function () {
        $('#magazine').turn({
            display: 'double',
            acceleration: true,
            gradients: !$.isTouch,
            elevation: 70,
            when: {
                turned: function (e, page) {
                    /*console.log('Current view: ', $(this).turn('view'));*/
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(window).bind('keydown', function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 37)
            $('#magazine').turn('previous');
        else if (e.keyCode == 39)
            $('#magazine').turn('next');
    });


    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    var pdfDoc, pageNum, scale, canvas, ctx;

    function Init() {
        pdfDoc = null;
        pageNum = 1;
        scale = 1.5;
        canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    }
    //
    // Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page
    //
    function renderPage(num) {
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });
        document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
        document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Init();
        PDFJS.getDocument('LIBROO2.pdf').then(function (doc) {
            pdfDoc = doc;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        });
    });

    // Go to previous page
    function goPrevious() {
        if (pageNum <= 1)
            return;
        pageNum--;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    // Go to next page
    function goNext() {
        if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages)
            return;
        pageNum++;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }
```

> IMAGEN DE EJEMPLO
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con display **flex**, es muy fácil de usarlo y entenderlo, ademas que los contenedores se ajustan dependiendo el contenido del elemento.

```css
#magazine{
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
        width: 1052px;
        height: 652px;  
        background-color: brown;
        margin: 5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

#the-canvas{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="magazine">
    <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Como recomendación en cuanto a medidas de asignación como height o width, etc, utiliza una medida para todos los elementos de tu sitio, como : **%, px, em,** evita combinarlas.

**NOTA.** Haz la prueba en tu navegador, en e visualizador de aquí no se ve bien.